# Menu using Tiles and SubTiles with pure CSS

Tags: css

I try to make a menu with tiles and sub-Tiles with pure CSS.
when click on one of the tiles of one color, all other tiles disappear and only the sub-tiles of that color appear.
I face the problem that only the tiles in div after that tile disappear.
the tiles be in div before that tile don't.
image describe the experiment.
check the code snippet.
thanks in advance 
Cheers
Chris

```css
#reset + label { display: block; }

label { display: none }
input[type="radio"] { display: none; }
div { display: none; }

input[type="radio"]:checked + label ~ label,
input[type="radio"]:checked + label ~ label ~ div { display: none; }

input[type="radio"]:checked + label ~ div { display: block; }

input[type="radio"][id="reset"]:checked ~ label { display: block; }

div {
    transition:all 1s;
}
label {
    width:23%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    background:#ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    color:#222222;
    padding:0.5%;
    margin:0.5%;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    transition:all 1s;
}
.tile, .sub-tile {
    width:23%;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    transition:all 1s;
    margin:0.5%;
    padding:0.5%;
}

.green, .top-green{
    background:#66dd99;
}
.blue, .top-blue {
    background:#6666ff;
}
.red, .top-red {
    background:#ff4466;
}
.purple, .top-purple {
    background:purple;
}
```

```html
 <input type="radio" name="color" class="reset" checked id="reset" />
    <label for="reset">Reset</label>

    <input type="radio" id="blue" class="blue" name="color" />
        <label for="blue" class="tile top-blue">BLUE</label>
        <div class="sub-tile blue">1</div>
        <div class="sub-tile blue">2</div>
        <div class="sub-tile blue">3</div>
        <div class="sub-tile blue">4</div>
        <div class="sub-tile blue">5</div>
        <div class="sub-tile blue">6</div>


        <input type="radio" id="red" class="red" name="color"/>
        <label for="red" class="tile top-red">RED</label>

        <div class="sub-tile red">7</div>
        <div class="sub-tile red">8</div>
        <div class="sub-tile red">9</div>
        <div class="sub-tile red">10</div>

        <input type="radio" id="purple" class="purple" name="color"/>
        <label for="purple" class="tile top-purple">PURPLE</label>

        <div class="sub-tile purple">16</div>
        <div class="sub-tile purple">17</div>
        <div class="sub-tile purple">18</div>
        <div class="sub-tile purple">19</div>
        <div class="sub-tile purple">20</div>
        <div class="sub-tile purple">21</div>

        <input type="radio" id="green" class="green" name="color"/>
        <label for="green" class="tile top-green">GREEN</label>
        <div class="sub-tile green">12</div>
        <div class="sub-tile green">13</div>
        <div class="sub-tile green">14</div>
        <div class="sub-tile green">15</div>
```

Comment: You need to select previous elements and CSS does not have it, because it traverses DOM only once.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you could try to achieve that with the following bare bones snippet.

*EDIT* note that you need to set the #reset initial value as checked

```css
#reset + label { display: block; }

label { display: none }
input[type="radio"] { display: none }
div { display: none }

input[type="radio"]:checked + label ~ label,
input[type="radio"]:checked + label ~ label ~ div { display: none }

input[type="radio"]:checked + label ~ div { 
   display: block;
   animation: fade-in 1s;
}

input[type="radio"][id="reset"]:checked ~ label { display: block }

.red { color: red }
.blue { color: blue }
.orange { color: orange }

@keyframes fade-in {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 1 }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="color" class="reset" checked id="reset" />
<label for="reset">Reset</label>

<input type="radio" name="color" class="blue" id="blue" />
<label for="blue">Blue</label>

<div class="sub-tile blue">1</div>
<div class="sub-tile blue">2</div>
<div class="sub-tile blue">3</div>

<input type="radio" name="color" class="red" id="red" />
<label for="red">Red</label>

<div class="sub-tile red">1</div>
<div class="sub-tile red">2</div>
<div class="sub-tile red">3</div>

<input type="radio" name="color" class="orange" id="orange" />
<label for="orange">orange</label>

<div class="sub-tile orange">1</div>
<div class="sub-tile orange">2</div>
<div class="sub-tile orange">3</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: Guys it works perfectly but I do not see now how to keep animation when disappear.

Comment: @djchrisclue can you post an updated fiddle of your code?

Comment: I just updated the code. thanks in advance for your help

Comment: @djchrisclue i made some adjusments to my answer. Also you can your modified code here:  https://jsfiddle.net/VilleKoo/9uo1pwty/

Comment: Thank you so much. you saved me a lot of time and I learnt a lot. if you plan to come to Bali you will be my guest in my villa.

Comment: @djchrisclue Glad i could you help you out! Next destination, Bali! :D By the way can you mark my answer accepted?

Comment: I think I need your help again.

Comment: I am serious about Bali.I think I need your help again. i made first the code in a separated html /css. then I wanted to integrate it my project... too bad it starts again the same problem..

Comment: could you give me a link where the problem is explain so i could fix it?

Comment: I solved the problem. it was an overwrite of the css from bootstrap.